# Selecting items from an array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to take an array of integers such as:

[1,2,3,4,9,10,11,12,18,19,20,21] and get the values at which there is a "jump," so, the output of my program would be [1,9,18]. I wrote the following code in Python which seems to be taking forever to run:

```
min_indices = np.where(data[:,1] == data[:,1].min())
start_indices = np.array([0])
i = 1
while (i < len(min_indices[0])):
    if (min_indices[0][i] != (min_indices[0][i-1] + 1)):
        start_indices.append(min_indices[i])
print start_indices
```

Comment: You never increment `i` in your loop, this is causing running forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,9,10,11,12,18,19,20,21]
>>> [a[i] for i,_ in enumerate(a[1:]) if (a[i]!=a[i-1]+1)]
[1, 9, 18]
```

and using zip:

```
>>> [a[0]]+[i for (i,j) in zip(a[1:],(a[:-1])) if (i!=j+1)]
[1, 9, 18]
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not incrementing "i" that I can tell.

Comment: Thanks. Forgot about that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`numpy.diff`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) with [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) here:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,9,10,11,12,18,19,20,21])
>>> indices = np.where(np.diff(a) > 1)[0] + 1
>>> np.concatenate(([a[0]], a[indices]))
array([ 1,  9, 18])
```